# Fastest way to implement listdir function in the python dropbox-api

Tags: python, dropbox-api, listdir

I've a question regarding python and [dropobox-api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#DropboxClient!).

I would need to download the whole content of a specific dropbox folder; standard python sftp library allows you to do this through `sftp.listdir()`, dropbox-api doesn't seem to support this feature. You could use the `DropoxClient.get_file(from_path, rev=None, start=None, length=None)`, but this implies you know the from_path value (that **must be a file**, **not a folder**).

I'm wondering whether using the solution below which be the correct way to achieve the `sftp.listdir()`feature.

Please note the below is pseudo-code, I didn't post client initialisation for the sake of brevity.

```
dir_content = []
folder_metadata = dropbox_client.metadata(my_folder) #this gives you folder metadata information
folder_content = folter_metadata("contents")
for element in folder_content:
    path = element["path"]
    if path.split(".") > 1: dir_content.append(path) #checking if it's an actual file or a folder
```

Any suggestion here?

Alessio

Comment: There's a boolean attribute `'is_dir'`

Comment: @PeterWood where is it?

Comment: [**`DropboxClient.metadata`**](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.metadata) has `is_dir` on each element in `content`.

Comment: I've seen it now, thanks Peter!

Comment: You can also use [DropboxClient.delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.delta) to list folders recursively.